# How to remove MIME boundary from uploaded file using Jersey 2.0 / Dropbox API

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, dropbox-api, jersey-client, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to implement REST client for Dropbox with Jersey 2.0.

Following code works fine and my file is successfully uploaded to Dropbox.

```
    String targetUrl = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&root=dropbox&path=Public/" + file.getName();
    WebTarget target = client.target(targetUrl);
    final FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", file);
    final MultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart().bodyPart(filePart);
    Response response = target.request()
            .put(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType()));
```

However, unnecessary MIME boundary is included in the uploaded file.

original file :

```
response : {
    "hash": "3ebf46d672258e1e190b70cc1f0dd5ce", 
    "revision": 87707813, 
…

"size": "0 bytes"}
```

uploaded file :

```
--Boundary_1_393888375_1373874680685
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="Dropbox.txt"; modification-date="Fri, 12 Jul 2013 04:23:29 GMT"; size=1328; name="file"

response : {
    "hash": "3ebf46d672258e1e190b70cc1f0dd5ce", 
    "revision": 87707813, 
…

"size": "0 bytes"}

--Boundary_1_393888375_1373874680685--
```

Is it possible to remove MIME boundary from the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

You see boundaries because you have `text/plain` inside `multipart/form-data`.

Answering your question, yes, If you change your code to upload using `text/plain`, boundaries will go way.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I'll try to change my code to upload using text/plain (not multipart/form-data).

Comment: What solution did you use ?